# command server by sending messages using twilio

Tags: meteor, twilio, arduino-uno

I am building a system to monitor a solar panel system using an arduino. The arduino is to interact with the user through SMS directly without needing internet.

However, I also want to allow the arduino to send data through sms to my application containing which it will read off the solar panel system. The idea is to allow the web app to receive data from the arduino without the arduino being connected to the internet. I would like to use Twilio SMSing service to achieve this whether any international number from African countries for e.g. will successfully be able to send SMSs to the server.

My question is whether there could be problems regarding receiving smses from international countries (in Africa for e.g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to [receive SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) on a Twilio number from international locales (accounting for message enablement and carrier details).

If however you want to send SMS globally from a Twilio number, I suggest you follow [these guidelines](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-is-global-sms-and-how-does-it-work).